# Add a custom UIWebView using Phonegap

Tags: ios, cordova, webview

I have an iOS app that needs OAuth authentication of a Facebook account, but I have to use my own server for the API calls.
So I want to open a FBLogin screen (UIWebView), with a login URL, when a certain button is clicked.

I have the following code:

FBWebViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface FBWebViewController : UIViewController <UIWebViewDelegate>
- (void)initFBWebView;
@end
```

FBWebViewController.m

```
- (void)initFBWebView {
NSLog(@"DetailViewController->initUIWebView {");

    UIWebView *aWebView;

    //  init and create the UIWebView
    aWebView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 400)];
    aWebView.autoresizesSubviews = YES;
    aWebView.autoresizingMask=(UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth);

    //set the web view delegates for the web view to be itself
    [aWebView setDelegate:self];

    //Set the URL to go to for your UIWebView
    NSString *urlAddress = @"http://www.google.com";

    //Create a URL object.
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlAddress];

    //URL Requst Object
    NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    //load the URL into the web view.
    [aWebView loadRequest:requestObj];

    //add the web view to the content view
    [self.view addSubview:aWebView];

}
```

and in my Authorize.m file, which handles all the API calls etc.

```
- (void)fbLogin:(NSMutableArray*)arguments withDict:(NSMutableDictionary*)options {
    FBWebViewController *webview = [[FBWebViewController alloc] init];
    [webview view];
    [webview initFBWebView];
}
```

Nothing happens. No WebView is opened. I put some debug statements in the initWithFbWebView method, and the method is called and run until the end, but no screen is showing up.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: i think u will not be able to do this since phonegap itself is a webview.....

Comment: If Phonegap consists of WebView, then why wouldn't it be able to open a custum WebView as well?

Comment: if u want to make some changes to the current one,then it is possible na......

Comment: What do you mean by 'current one' and 'na'?

Comment: i mean u can make some changes to the existing webview

Comment: if u r able to make some changes to the webview[provided by phonegap] then why u need one more.........

Comment: Have you looked at https://github.com/davejohnson/phonegap-plugin-facebook-connect/ ?